# Set selected option via CSS?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, html-select

Is it possible to set the `selected` attribute of an `option` tag via a CSS class?

I'm wondering if something like the following is possible in a stylesheet:

```
option.selected {
  selected: true;
}
```

Then in HTML:

```
<option class="selected">
```

Which would have the same effect as setting the `selected` attribute.  Is this technique possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nope, CSS only alters the presentation, not the content (although CSS3 does support some modification of content, but not the selection of values.) You'll need to use JavaScript if you can't modify the HTML directly.

Answer (score 3):

```
option[selected] {background-color:skyblue;color:white;}
```

in case you want to show the previous marked selection - independend of the changes from the user after displaying a result, the old selected remain sykblue, the new changes are in darkblue.

Answer (score 2):

Not via CSS, but it can be accomplished via javascript.

```
function setSelects() {

    var allSelects = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
    for (var i = 0; i < allSelects.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < allSelects[i].options.length; j++) {
            if (allSelects[i].options[j].className == "selected") {

                allSelects[i].selectedIndex = j;
            }
        }
    }
}

window.onload = setSelects;
```

As other people have pointed out, I'm not sure why you'd want to do it via a CSS class in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If you use JQuery then you can do something very much along those lines, but not CSS on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, but I am not sure about IE

Below code will change style for **default selected** item.

```
           <style>
           option[selected="selected"] {
           color:red;
           font-weight:bold
           }
           </style>

           <select>
           <option value="1">Txt</option>
           <option value="2" selected="selected">Another Txt</option>
           </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Selected is not a CSS property.  See the spec at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/propidx.html.