# Can html select dropdowns be styled differently with just css depending on initial selected value?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, styling

I'm trying to separate data from css presentation for a collection of dropdowns.  One thing that I'm finding difficult is highlighting select dropdowns that are pre-populated with a users currently chosen.  I can style the text color of the dropdown *options* as much as I want, but can't get the text of the at-rest select box to change (In firefox, at least)

http://jsfiddle.net/tchalvakspam/YmmvU/

Is a jsfiddle showing what I mean.

What I'd like to do is:

change the color of the dropdowns when they start out with an option value other than '' (empty string default option) selected.  make them red to highlight

Is this possible with pure css, or am I forced to use js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code

```
#smart-search-form option[selected=selected]{
    color: #ff0000 !important;
}
```

Doesn't work because when you select an option, you change its property `selected`, but not its attribute `selected`. So the selector `[selected=selected]` only matches the default option.

It seems you need something like `option:selected`, but THAT DOESN'T EXIST.

(See [Set selected option via CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122036/set-selected-option-via-css))

Comment: Yeah, browsers really don't want to support coloring of select dropdowns much.  Mobile dropdowns, for example, have a totally different browser defined style that's very incompatible with css styling.  In addition browsers like chrome (and firefox to an extent) seem to discourage or prevent styling of dropdown options excessively, so going with js or nothing is probably best I can get.